# firebase database text data saved as appcompattextview

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

i am wondering as to why is my text displayed as "androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText" in firebase database, and not as string?

[image: pic for reference]

Comment: did u set the value as a string after u get it from the edittext ?

Comment: You need to extract text from edittext. For that use editText.getText().toString().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That happens when you pass your `EditText` object instead of the actual text.

> androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText

This is what `editText.toString()` looks like when being casted to String

---

You should use:

```
editText.getText().toString()
```

instead of:

```
editText.toString()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `editText.getText().toString().trim()` instead of `editText.toString()`

Comment: thank u, but i pass most values as strings. but, still the same result... will post code snippets later.

Comment: its irrelevant how you pass values, using `editText.getText().toString().trim()` will ensure that everything in that textbox is converted to string at all times